# Issue with Bash Script not displaying

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to read in a Log File separated with "|" and when i run the command just in the terminal it works, but now in my script it wont display the argument when its set to a variable (logFile). Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
logFile = $1

tput cup 5 10; 
echo "What would you like to view from the daily report file:" 
tput cup 6 12; 
echo "$logFile" 
tput cup 8 11; 
echo "1 -- Daily Processes" 
tput cup 9 11; 
echo "2 -- Users" 
tput cup 10 11; 
echo "3 -- Total Process Time for User"

# read input from user 
tput cup 12 10; 
echo -n "Your Selection?" 
read choice

#process choice 
case "$choice" in 
1) awk -F"|" '{print $2}'$1|uniq|sort -n 
;; 
2) awk -F"|" '{print $1}'$2|uniq|sort -n 
;;
*) echo "Invalid Choice..." 
;; 
esac
```

Comment: Remove the spaces around variable assignment - `logFile=$1`.

Comment: Lolol whoops. I fixed that, but my awk still isnt outputting anything.

Comment: You need a space to separate the awk command from the filename, i.e. `'{print $2}' $1` instead of `'{print $2}'$1`

Comment: Include a sample of what your log file contains.

Comment: Please learn to use https://shellcheck.net **before** posting here. You'll save time for -everyone, including yourself :-) . Good luck.